# Different line chart for local & remote json file using NVD3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am have created a line chart using NVD3, however, something very weird is happening. When I created the cahrt local and tested it with a json file on my machine I am able to obtain a line chart with two series. When I change the d3.json url to point to a web service API it only returns a line chart with one series. Two rule out that my test file was different I copied the json the service api was returning saved it to a local file and still it returns 2 series.

Its weird that the same data is displayed differently. ANy idea what could cause this?

My code

```
d3.json("json/test.json", function(error, data) {
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .x(function(d) { return d.timestamp; })
            .y(function(d) { return d.value/100; })
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
            .isArea(true)
            //.forceY([0]);
        chart.xAxis
            .showMaxMin(true)
            .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(d)); });
        chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('Response Time(ms)')
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
        d3.select('#qosChart1 svg')
            .datum(data.seriesSet)
            .transition().duration(500)
            .call(chart);
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        return chart;
    });
});
```

Data Sample

```
{
  "seriesSet": [
    {
      "key": "VAS response time",
      "disabled": false,
      "values": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1406800800000,
          "value": "10.0"
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 1406800860000,
          "value": "10.823879"
        }
        ....
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "Bob's activities",
      "disabled": true,
      "values": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1406800800000,
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 1406800860000,
          "value": null
        }
        ....
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry **no problems with NVD3**...the problem was with the service API query and the response the server was giving